# C++ Add lines from system(command) to a vector<string>

Tags: c++

I want to add the lines outputted by the code below into a `vector<string>`. Is there an easy way to do this directly without having to save the output to a text file then parsing the file?

```
char command[50] = 'ls - l';
system(command)
```

Comment: What would the `vector<string>` store; one string per line?

Comment: There's no way using `system`. There is a more complicated way which involves creating a separate process and capturing the standard output from that process. But how you do that varies depending on what operating system you are working with.

Comment: Yes, I would like the vector to store one line at a time